# Trouble with converting ordered int array to ordered array list

Tags: java

My professor gave us this code that creates a sorted int array and wants us to convert it to a sorted array list with strings. This is an assignment on maintenance and must reflect the original code. So, I can't use the size method, Collections.sort(), or anything that doesn't reflect the original code.

We are given

```
    OrderedIntList() {
    a = new int[10];
}

    public void insert(int v) {
    if(c == 0) {
        a[0]= v;
        c++;
    } else {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++, j++) {
            if(v < a[i]) 
                break;
        }
        for (int i = c; i > j; i--) {
            a[i] = a[i - 1];
        }

        a[j]= v; 
        c++;
    }
}
```

This is what I have come up with to convert it to an array list

```
        stringList() {
    list = new ArrayList<String>(10);
}

    public void insert(String element) {
    if(c == 0) {
        list.add(0, element);
        c++;
    } else {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++, j++) {
            if(element.compareTo(list.get(i)) == -1) 
                break;
        }
        for (int i = c; i > j; i--) {
            list.set(i, list.get(0));
        }

        list.set(j, element);
        c++;
    }
}
```

It keeps throwing an exception on

```
list.set(i, list.get(0));
```

When debugging I see that ArrayList.class is throwing the exception because the index equals the size. I can't seem to come up with a solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: You need to use the `add` method to increase the size of a list.  You can't do it just by calling `set` on elements that you haven't inserted yet.

Comment: What @David Wallace said, also even if set did allow this, your line                list.set(i, list.get(0)); isn't the same as a[i] = a[i - 1], you are doing something like a[i] = a[0]. So you have two bugs.

Also I'm just guessing that you are misinterpreting what list = new ArrayList<String>(10); does, in this case it doesn't make a list of 10 strings it just uses the number 10 as a "hint" to set the initial capacity (which is not the size) to 10

Comment: @ben it's not a "hint". It's the actual size. As per the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-): ***Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity***

Comment: Hi @Bohemian , you are right in that the capacity is the list's "size" in memory. When I say size I mean the "size()" of the list, which is the number of elements actually in the list. You are mistaken if you think capacity is the number of actual elements in the list.

Comment: @ben ah, right. capacity != size.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting aspect of this assignment is that arrays and lists have a significant difference in behaviour: arrays have a fixed size while lists expand as items are added. For lists, adding items anywhere other than the end is an insert and it automatically moves the items to the right to make room. That doesn't happen with an array so it needs to be done manually in the code you are refactoring.

So, in my opinion, the correct minimal refactoring of an array to a list is to turn the `set` into an `insert` and then remove the code that used to be required to shift elements. It's no longer required for a list:

```
public void insert(String element) {
    if (c == 0) {
        list.add(element);
        c++;
    } else {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++, j++) {
            if (element.compareTo(list.get(i)) < 0 ) 
                break;
        }
        list.insert(j, element);
        c++;
    }
}
```

For lists, adding to an empty list is the same as inserting at position 0. So the specially handling for an empty list is completely unnecessary. But that might be not 'reflecting the original' code.

Another more subtle difference is that this code won't cause an error if more than 10 items are inserted. To correctly reflect the behaviour of the initial code you would need to specifically add a test for that.

```
if (c == MAX_SIZE)
    throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(c);
```

It's likely your assignment is not expect you to handle that condition but it is worth knowing that the refactoring is changing the behaviour of the function if it's not included.

Comment: @Bohemian how is this answer irrelevant? Rather, the arraylist does have enough capacity to hold all elements - but this answer stands despite that fact.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to your problem is instead of

```
stringList() {
  list = new ArrayList<String>(10);
}
```

do

```
stringList() {
  list = new ArrayList<String>(10);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      list.add("");
  }
}
```

because only this will achieve a list of 10 strings, the first just makes a list that has the capacity to hold 10 strings (which is more of a performance hint)

Comment: @Bohemian, you are right in that there is no need to initially populate the data structure. However, the change I proposed is correct. I believe you mean to propose an alternative approach that does not prepopulate the datastructure and that adds elements to the tail of the list during insert, instead of using set(). That will work because this is insertion sort, however what I proposed should also work.